# Create Entity Framework TPH Discriminator column by Data Annotation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-annotations, table-per-hierarchy

I would like to create Discriminator column by Data Annotation.

```
[Table("Book")]
public partial class Book
{
    public long BookID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string name { get; set; }

    public int? page { get; set; }

}
```

mapping by Fluent

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
            .Map<StoryBook>(m => m.Requires("typetitle").HasValue("story"));
```

Anyway I need to have discriminator column value in select result

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to create Discriminator column by Data Annotation.

You can't annotate a property that's not there.

With TPH inheritance, the discriminator property is not part of the class model. This is because setting its value to another type's value would create an ambiguity: type A, marked as type B. So EF just prevents developers from doing that.

So: mapping TPH inheritance can only be done by fluent mapping.

> Anyway I need to have discriminator column value in select result

If you need the discriminator value in code, this usually is a telltale that you either don't apply inheritance the way it should, or you shouldn't use inheritance at all. One indicator against using inheritance is when there are cases in which the "type" of objects should be changed at runtime (i.e. the value of the discriminator is changed).

Comment: How can I see the discriminator property value in result. i.e. `context.Books.Find(2)`

Comment: Like I said, you can't. It's not an exposed property. When inheritance is used well, you don't need to know which subtype you're dealing with. That's the point of polymorphism. If you do need to know the type at runtime, my advice is not to use inheritance, but to use a type property and act upon its value. But this discussion is beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: BTW, you can get a collection of subtypes by `context.Books.OfType<StoryBook>()`.

Comment: I know but there are several values for discriminator that I don't want to mapping them to any class. Also I found that there is not any way to change the discriminator value i.e. ` change from story to history`

Comment: Man, you really should NOT use inheritance here. Your discriminator should just be a regular property that conditions behavior. Did you understand what I said above? Suppose you have a `StoryBook` instance and you could change its discriminator to "history", that doesn't mean that the runtime type is magically changed! And how is EF supposed to save this.? The type says "discriminator=storybook", the property (if it was there) would say "discriminator=history".

Comment: And if there are discriminator values that you don't want to map to any class then EF will never materialize these records into objects. You can't define a type that corresponds with "all other discriminators". Please think about this carefully and try to grasp the concepts you're playing with.

Comment: Imagine that we have several books in various type (Story, History, Poem,...) so they have same field title as each other but their types is different. End user should have ability to set BookA as story but he also should has ability to modify it and changing it from story to history, isn't it?

Comment: You tell me. For me it's totally clear that you don't need inheritance here. "Type" is just an attribute of a `Book`. What if new types are introduced? Do you want to have to change the code for each new type?