# EF Core HasData Seeding a TPH Entity

Tags: entity-framework-core

I want to use the EF Core `HasData` method to seed a database with reference data. Two of the models I want to seed follow the Table per Hierarchy (TPH) pattern in the sense that there is a none abstract base type and another none abstract derived type. These models in the database exist in a table named after the base type with a discriminator column. I would like to add data seeding for this table. However I’m struggling to find any guidelines of how to do so in the EF Core 6 documentation.

I have a few related questions:

Do I seed all the data using the `HasData` method on an `EntityTypeBuilder<BaseType>` or do I need to split the seeding into one `HasData` on that class and another on `EntityTypeBuilder<DerivedType>`?

I understand using TPH will add a shadow discriminator property and that, potentially, I’ll have to add that in the data seeding. Does that mean I have to use anonymous types to specify that property (doesn’t seem very elegant) and if so, can I get the autogenerated discriminator name using a method (typing it manually sounds like a risk as what if EF Core changes the discriminator name convention?)?

Should I be avoiding using TPH on reference tables altogether? Is there something else I should do instead?

Answer (score 1):

After going through my options with trial and error, I have come to the following solution. It may not be perfect, but it deals with all of my concerns.

> Do I seed all the data using the `HasData` method on an `EntityTypeBuilder<BaseType>` or do I need to split the seeding into one `HasData` on that class and another on `EntityTypeBuilder<DerivedType>`?

You have to do it on both classes, attempting otherwise throws on creating the migration:
`The seed entity for entity type 'BaseType' cannot be added because the value provided is of a derived type 'DerivedType'. Add the derived seed entities to the corresponding entity type.`

> I understand using TPH will add a shadow discriminator property and that, potentially, I’ll have to add that in the data seeding. Does that mean I have to use anonymous types to specify that property (doesn’t seem very elegant) and if so, can I get the autogenerated discriminator name using a method (typing it manually sounds like a risk as what if EF Core changes the discriminator name convention?)?

I have added a property to the `BaseType` class and defined it as the discriminator, so now I can specify the discriminator values directly without using anonymous type and I am in control of the discriminator values. Gert Arnold points out [in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36105263/18365832) why this might not be appropriate. However I have used the following method described [in this EF Core Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/7586) to hopefully mitigate the concerns he raised.

> Should I be avoiding using TPH on reference tables altogether? Is there something else I should do instead?

This is still unanswered. But I am feeling a lot more confident it is a good approach now.

Comment: Did your strategy work out as expected?  Can you add a sample of your configuration and data seeding to your answer?